# Adding the numbers of textbox giving wrong result

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am creating a web app in which I have a number in my `$scope` variable

```
$scope.total=20;
```

and I have one textbox

```
<input type="text" ng-model="amount1" ng-change="amountchange(amount1)" />
```

and when a user enters 500 in the textbox it should be 700 but instead the answer is coming 755 and when I delete 500 from my textbox it became `null`.

I just want to add or remove from my textbox what I am doing wrong here

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XNVj3/2244/) created by me for better understanding

Comment: don't understand what is expectation?

Comment: On each number entered, the `$scope.total` value is updated. Ex: When entering 500, first `5 + 200`, then `50 + 205` and then `500 + 255`. Check console [**here**](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/XNVj3/2245/)

Comment: And btw, you don't need to pass `amount1` to `amountchange()`.

Comment: but still the value is coming null instead of 200 if i delete from textbox

Answer (score 1):

this problem is in this line:

```
$scope.total = parseInt($scope.amount1) + parseInt($scope.total);
```

you aggregate the value when you enter more input instead of just sowing the result.

what you can do is simple, add this method:

```
 $scope.getTotal=function(){
    return parseInt($scope.amount1) + parseInt($scope.total);
}
```

and replace `{{total}}` with this: `{{getTotal()}}`

Answer (score 0):

It happens because of ng-change, each time the value is getting added
On entering 500,

**Step1** 5 + 200
**Step2**  50 + 205
**Step3**  500 + 255

and  so it becomes 755. Use **[ng-blur](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBlur)** instead of ng-change

```
 <body data-ng-controller="myController">
  <input type="text" ng-model="amount1" ng-blur="amountchange()" />
 {{total}}
  </body>
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sajeetharan/9uwvcxmg/1)**

Comment: @Tushar i have added the explanation

Comment: but still the value is coming null instead of 200 if i delete from textbox

Comment: @MumbaiWadala check the update, it happens if the amount1 is empty http://jsfiddle.net/sajeetharan/9uwvcxmg/3/

Answer (score 0):

What happens in your app is actually expected, because you add the current number on each input change.

Changing to `ng-blur` or setting a timeout before updating the value, using the built-in `ng-model-options`, which can now be done as of Angular 1.6 (released just yesterday) could be good options.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="amount1" ng-change="amountchange()" ng-model-options="{'debounce':{'default':300}}" />
```

or:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="amount1" ng-blur="amountchange()" />
```

However, I do not recommend either of them, and here's why:

By not letting the user decide when the data they entered is submitted (e.g.: pressing `enter` or a submit button) you make it user-unfriendly as well as introduce unwanted behaviour, such as when the user clicks off and on the in the second example, the number will have been added again and again...

Consider using a form and `ng-submit` instead as it's cleaner, more semantic and also conveys a friendlier way for your users to submit data.

Also here's the solution to your other issue:

```
$scope.amountchange = function () {
        var amount = ($scope.amount1 != '') ? $scope.amount1 : 0;
        console.log(amount)
        if (amount != NaN) {
            $scope.total = parseInt(amount) + parseInt($scope.total);
        }
        else {
            alert("Please enter a number.");
            $scope.amount1 = $scope.total;
        }
 }
```

To explain: first off you did not make use of any arguments, so you do not need to pass the `amount1` model's value into the function in your directive. But that wasn't the problem. The reason why it set it to null is that the empty field doesn't parse to a `0`, therefore you have to set it yourself. I saved the value into the variable `amount` on the function and assigned either the value of `$scope.amount` or `0` if it happens to be empty.